# Why asafoetida clumps in hot oil?

Tags: vegetables, oil, indian-cuisine

**Introduction**

While making vegetable recipe we generally initiate with same procedure for every vegetable i.e. in 2 spoon of hot oil we put mustard, cumin, and asafoetida before adding pieces of any vegetable.

**Question**

Why does asafoetida clump after putting into hot oil? How to avoid this?

**Reference** -

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Nw4avBKHpw) -- Please refer initial process only in this video. Although she has not added asafoetida. I am just telling to refer initial common procedure for understanding.

Following is another image for reference

[image: oil]

Answer (score -2):

Naturally, asofoetida  is obtained as a hard gummy resin from trees. In order to make it easier to measure and add to your cooking, it is powdered and sold. But, asofoetida being a resin in nature gets clumped in the package if not coated with some agent. In India, it is usually coated with flour. Flour when put in oil gets fried. So what you see clumping isn't asofoetida, it's the flour in it.